# Where can I find the SSIS Precompile Property for Script Tasks in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I was getting an error after creating a Script Task in SSIS:

> Validation error. Script Task : The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.

The error was fixed (just need to BUILD the script successfully) and not relevant to the question.

During my search for answers on StackOverflow, I have found a lot of talks about this "pre-compile" setting, but after clicking on nearly everything in SSIS, I just couldn't find it, hence the question.

I had a suspicion that it was removed in a later version but just couldn't prove it. Please let me know if you happen to know the answer.

Comment: Potential issue for building on VS2019, Ver. 16.9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579019/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-in-c-at-line-0. If you get the message `Could not find part of path[...]` when building. The linked issue will also trigger this validation error because it can't build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer:

[Configuring the Script Component in the Script Component Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/data-flow-script-component/configuring-the-script-component-in-the-script-component-editor?view=sql-server-ver15)

> In SQL Server 2008 Integration Services (SSIS) and later versions, all
> scripts are precompiled. In previous versions, you specified whether
> scripts were precompiled by setting a Precompile property for the
> task.

I wish there is an easier way to locate feature differences between SQL versions.

UPDATE - Thanks to @billinkc, I have pinpointed the section where the change is documented:

[Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms141752(v=sql.100))

> Unlike earlier versions where you could indicate whether the scripts
> were precompiled, all scripts are precompiled in SQL Server 2008
> Integration Services (SSIS). When a script is precompiled, the
> language engine is not loaded at run time and the package runs more
> quickly. However, precompiled binary files consume significant disk
> space.