# The binary code for the script is not found” ssis

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ssis

when i try to add external component to ssis script component I am getting the following error:

> The binary code for the script is not found

I am using ssis 2013

Update:

No property called precompiled to set it to true

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329138/where-can-i-find-the-ssis-precompile-property-for-script-tasks-in-sql-server-200

Comment: Can you share more details about the script, external component, or package?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using other language than the one which is set in ScriptLanguage field in script Task Editor.

**Solution:**
1. Drag a new scrip task
2. Before clicking on Edit script button make sure you have right language in Scriptlanguage(either Visual studio or C#)