# SSIS script task "The binary code for the script is not found"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2012

This problem is very similiar to those:
["The binary code for the script is not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528349/the-binary-code-for-the-script-is-not-found) and
[The binary code for the script is not found” ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429350/the-binary-code-for-the-script-is-not-found-ssis)

I have an SSIS project with multiple script files. SSIS claims that one of them has no binary even though there should be. There are no code errors, and I can build it properly. I suspect it's a VS bug because this problem appears and disappears randomly. What I mean by that is that this script is working fine, I open it to see the contents, close and suddenly this error happens! So I open it like 20 times, and it (without me doing anything) repairs itself! Any ideas on how to make it work better? It seems (though I can't confirm with 100% certainty) that this problem happens when you save the SSIS script (as in use ctrl+s) instead of simply exiting from the VS.

Things that I have tried that sometimes work:

- Restarting Visual studio, opening the script without doing anything, closing it
- Adding a small change to the code, exiting
- Removing and adding breakpoints
- Going on my knees in the direction of Redmond, Washington, and chanting the names of M$ presidents while opening and closing windows in the building to the rhythm of the windows starting sound
- Randomly closing and opening the project, as well as going through items in the script component menu

Things that don't seem to work: rebuilding project, cleaning project, you know the standard stuff

Comment: All I can add is that in BIDS 2008, we suddenly had a situation where we couldn't open _any_ script files at all. The editor just crashed. Ever since then I avoid scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that OFTEN works. Notice the usage of often.

1) Try restarting your computer.

2) If it doesn't work go to your system temp files directory, and find the location of SSIS temp projects (you can also open the script, right click on C# project, explore in windows explorer). Delete the project. (Make copies before deleting just in case). Start Visual studio, and once again edit script, close, hope it works. DON'T SAVE THE SCRIPT PROJECT BEFORE CLOSING! JUST CLOSE!

Note that for the second step, you can also try using a cleaning tool, like CCleaner of similar.

Comment: Thank for suggestion. In my case, I did some idiotic changes to main package solution config manager and tried changing the "Target SERVER Version". That wiped out all the scripts project from each packages.  Then I came to know that it is auto-generation everytime we open. That means each package is storing script project within it. But now I don't know why its not generating while pressing on "Edit Script button"  (really pissed!)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did some idiotic changes to main package solution config manager and tried changing the "Target SERVER Version". That wiped out all the scripts project from each packages.  Then I came to know that it is auto-generation everytime we open. That means each package is storing script project within it. But now I don't know why its not generating while pressing on "Edit Script button"  (really pissed!)

Thank for suggestion. In my case, I did some idiotic changes to main package solution config manager and tried changing the "Target SERVER Version". That wiped out all the scripts project from each packages.  Then I came to know that it is auto-generation everytime we open. That means each package is storing script project within it. But now I don't know why its not generating while pressing on "Edit Script button"  (really pissed!)

"Lucky I am" .  got an fix!   Each package file was internally not linked with their Script.cs.  So I opened each package file in Notepad++ and found Script.cs content within. I recreated scripts.cs in each package (steps) and pasted the content from notepad++. And it worked!!!