# SSIS "The binary code or the script is not found" only on start_execution

Tags: ssis

When i launch my script from this stored procedure, it fails on the first script task.

> EXEC SSISDB.catalog.start_execution  @execution_id

I've got the following error:

> The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.

I've done this multiple times without results, i have a feeling that the problem must be somewhere else because when i launch it from Integration Services Catalogs it works.

I use SQL 2012 on local development computer and SQL 2016 on server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the SSIS Precompile Property for Script Tasks in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329138/where-can-i-find-the-ssis-precompile-property-for-script-tasks-in-sql-server-200)

Comment: There could be something to dig in, i use SQL 2012 on my COMPUTER and there's SQL2016 on the SERVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading.

I was using VS2012 to dev and deploy on SQL2016, when you do that the script component wont work.

I used VS2015 and upgraded package to SQL2016 and it worked.