# SSIS Error: Binary Code for script not found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a script task that I have copied the code from another package, which that package runs completely but I get this error when I try to run the new package:

```
Error: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
```

I have set the DelayValidation equal to true and the code is the same code from a script that will execute so I'm not sure what the error could be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the SSIS Precompile Property for Script Tasks in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329138/where-can-i-find-the-ssis-precompile-property-for-script-tasks-in-sql-server-200)

Comment: Open the script task and save it again, it will compile the script. There might be unsolved dependencies that the code uses and you don't have in your current environment (which you will have to solve for the script to run).

Comment: @EzLo If there are unsolved dependencies how do I find them?

Comment: When I go to build the script that I can't get to run I get the error 'WinSCP' could not be found. But the error doesn't show up for the script I copied the code from.

Comment: @TroyR You need to install (or copy and reference) the WinSCP .dll so the script can use it.